# Корректно ли двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Я уже упоминал, что за 4 года мы успели многого добиться: за это время наши инженеры и технические специалисты разработали довольно широкий модельный ряд продукции, которая в настоящее время производится.

Кажется, можно поставить "а именно" и вторая часть поясняет первую. Но не имеет ли значение то, что и в первой и во второй части говорится о времени: "за 4 года" и "за это время"?

И еще здесь:

Наверное, все будет зависеть от нашего государства: как оно повлияет на данную ситуацию, окажет ли поддержку российскому бизнесу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У первого предложения сомнительная стилистика (ненужные повторы, неверная структура последнего придаточного).

Предлагаемый вариант: Я уже упоминал, что за 4 года мы успели многого добиться:  наши инженеры и технические специалисты разработали и внедрили в производство довольно широкий модельный ряд продукции.

Второе предложение оформлено верно.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы оформила следующим образом:

Я уже упоминал, что за 4 года мы успели многого добиться: за это время наши инженеры и технические специалисты разработали довольно широкий модельный ряд продукции, которая теперь производится.

Наверное, все будет зависеть от нашего государства: как оно повлияет на данную ситуацию, окажет ли поддержку российскому бизнесу.

Comment: Не забудьте вопросительный знак в конце второго предложения